# addEventListener 'drop' not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, drag-and-drop, draggable

i'm using this code to make some items on the page draggable/droppable.
It's all OK on IE/FF/Chrome, but on Safari i got some trouble.
Putting some console.log() on each event, i've found that all events are recognized by safari except the most important 'drop' event.

Can anyone find out the solution to make this code working also on Safari?

```
prepareDrag:function () {
    if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
        var dragged = $SHS.j('a');
        $SHS.j.each(dragged, function (index, value) {
            value.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
                try {
                    var img = $SHS.j(this).find('img');
                    if ((img[0].nodeName).toUpperCase() == 'IMG') {
                        var commandData = img[0].src + '|' + value.href;
                        //Do Stuff
                    } else throw 'Non valido';
                } catch (err) {
                    //Errore
                }
            }, false);
            value.addEventListener('dragend', function (e) {
                //Do Stuff
            }, false);
        });
    }
},
prepareDrop:function () {
    if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
        var dropper = document.getElementById('dropArea');
        dropper.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
            $SHS.j("#dropArea").addClass('drop-over');
        }, false);

        dropper.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $SHS.j("#dropArea").removeClass('drop-over');
            //Do stuff
        }, false);

        dropper.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (e.preventDefault) {

                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $SHS.j("#dropArea").addClass('drop-over');
        }, false);

        dropper.addEventListener('dragleave', function (e) {
            $SHS.j("#dropArea").removeClass('drop-over');
        }, false);

    } else {

    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `e.preventDefault();` on `dragenter` as well.